# Database design for a tree: selection by parent, by layer or both

Tags: database-design, tree, relational-database

I want to store a tree (i.e. each item has exactly one parent, or none for the root node) of homogeneous items in a relational database. There are occasional writes to the tree, most often a leaf node to be added somewhere and less frequently an intermediate node to be added.

Two two most common types of query are:

1. Select all items which **have a specific parent**.
2. Select all items which **are in a specific layer** / at a specific depth in the tree.

Storing only the parent of each item (null for the root node), the first case is easy. For the second case I'd have to iterate and count the parents of each item until I reach the root node, or store the layer explicitly, introducing redundancy.

What are my options for the structure of this database? The database may have a couple of thousand entries. My goal is to make both types of queries fast.

Comment: Look into closure tables: http://technobytz.com/closure_table_store_hierarchical_data.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is for databases that support Recursive Common Table Expressions (anything but MySQL really).

You should use an Adjacency List:

```
create table foo (
  id int primary key,
  name text not null,
  parent_id int null references foo(id)
);
```

Your query would be something like this:

```
with recursive expression1 as (

  --select the root node:
  select
    id,
    name,
    1 as level
  from foo
  where
    parent_id is null

  union all

  select
    current.id,
    current.name,
    previous.level + 1 as level
  from foo current
  join expression1 as previous on current.parent_id = previous.id
)

select * from expression1
where
  level = ?;
```

This calculates the level for every row in the table, so it might be possible to optimize it, but I'm not exactly sure how. A materialized view is an option.

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ad19f/10

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I'm forced to use MySQL, could you elaborate on my options? Also, how does this approach compare to simply setting the level by hand on every possible edit operation?

Comment: @Daerst try PostgreSQL if you can. If you have to use MySQL then look at the Nested Set Pattern